# What is the difference between "Fuzzy Logic" and "General Predicate Logic with Identity and Function Symbols"?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, fuzzy-logic

I understand the Fuzzy Logic is a infinite-value logic. But can GPLIF's function symbols in conjunction with predicates be used as an alternative to the degrees of truth provided by fuzzy logic? What problem is fuzzy logic solving?

Comment: How do you suppose the former would do the work of the latter?